# Expected time to return

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $\phi(i) = E(number \space of steps \space to \space reach \space 5 | X_0=i), i \in S=\{1, 2, 3, 4,5\}$. When I am trying to find $\phi(1)$, suppose  I have the following equations:

$\phi(5) = 0$

$\phi(6) = 1 + (1/2) \phi(5) + (1/2) \phi(4)$

$\phi(4) = 1 + (1/2) \phi(6) + (1/2) \phi(3)$

$\phi(3) = 1 + (1/4) \phi(1) + (1/4) \phi(2)$

$\phi(1) = 1 + \phi(3)$

$\phi(6) = 1 + \phi(3)$

I just wonder where the 1 comes from in the above equations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It takes $1$ move $+$ some other number of moves given in terms of $\phi$ to reach $5$ from any other point.

Comment: You seem to be lacking some context here. The equations seem to imply the manner of possible steps and their probability, which I assume you did not mention. I don't think people can explain the equations without the admissible steps and their probabilities.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to enter the transition matrix here. Thanks for the first answer. It is clear for me now.